# how to select a combobox value in webbrowser vb.net

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, google-account

How can I select a value in gmail registration (https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?) Specifically in the month and sex field? I noticed that it is different from other sites and I could not fit a code.
Here is the code I found online:

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName ("select")
        If element.GetAttribute ("name") = "BirthMonth" Then
            Element.SetAttribute ("value", "August")
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: You will have to post something if you want help.

Comment: What do you mean? How do you post something?

Comment: Post some code, please.

Comment: ok, I put the code.

Comment: UP!!!!!!!!!!!!!